# How do i change these panel settings in Kubuntu (see attached image). Is it possible?

Tags: kubuntu, kde

[image: KDE Panel]

So i want to

1. Change the icon size of the window tab icon.
2. Change the width of the window tab.
3. Disable panel-pinning completely.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance